# Screw Shell on light bulb burnt / black after light bulb died

Tags: smell, bulb

Should I be concerned that the candelabra on a decorative incandescent bulb was blackened / burnt after the light bulb died?

Bulb is hanging from an open air kitchen chandelier. lt created a terrible smell like burnt plastic after it died

Comment: Was it blackened on the inside of the bulb or in the screw shell?

Comment: Screw shell, filament looked like just a typical burnt it filament.

Comment: If this is true then, when the filament burned-up in the bulb, (typically a fairly good current surge accompanies the bulb burn-out)  the current surge overwhelmed the ability of the light socket to conduct this load resulting in this flash.  This carbon splash left in the socket (the black residue) can be expected to cause problems in the future.  Consider replacing at least the socket if not the entire fixture.

Comment: This is not that uncommon with poor quality sockets. Also this can be the result of a bulb that is not secured tightly.